# Is it okay to put 3/4" plywood over 1/2" wood subfloor?

Tags: floor, replacement, plywood

I recently purchased a 2 level condo and took out existing hardwood floor on the 2nd floor. Some of the pieces of plywood is pretty old. I wanted to get an honest opinion on whether I should replace the plywood or put plywood on top? The current plywood is 1/2" wood. Would this cause me problems later? I am planning to keep the property and want to ensure I am making the right decision. The joist on the rim of the rooms are under the walls which would make it difficult to replace from what I'm understanding.

Any thoughts? My head is spinning..Help!

Answer (score 3):

There are no structural issues with putting extra subfloor on existing subfloor.  The only issue this would cause would be matching of the floor heights and possibly your first stair height.

(and trim - subfloor could make you reinstall/cut all trim)

(and make sure the old subfloor is even/flat or patch it first)